# Meteor: Desktop and mobile view

Tags: meteor, mobile, view, desktop

I have a meteor project which I've created for desktop view.  Now I'd like to create mobile views for it as well.  I'm using bootstrap so it's not a scalability issue.  I want the mobile version to show information differently.

Could I achieve this without building two separate apps?

I'm using iron:router so I was wondering if I could make certain templates show for if the device is desktop and other templates render if the device is mobile/tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed - you can use this device detection package from Atmosphere: https://atmospherejs.com/mystor/device-detection

> A common use case for device detection is to serve a different user experience to the user based on what their device type is. This will often involve different templates to be displayed to the user.